# Plotly Dash bar chart with dynamically changing bar width (or dynamically changing graphing frequencies)

Tags: python, charts, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I have a bar graph made using Plotly Dash that looks like below. I have daily data from 2006 to now (2021) which makes the bar width very small. I am wondering if there is any way to plot and show a lower frequency graph when viewing in a larger timeframe(Y2006-Y2021) but show a detailed, higher frequency graph in a smaller timeframe(say, 2020 Mar to 2020 June).

[image: Bar Graph Output]

The solution I can think of now is to pre-process the data in Pandas before plotting, but it won't be dynamically changing when I zoom in. How can I graph a dynamic graph with changing graphing frequencies? Below is my code.

````
df_data = df_data.dropna(subset=['date'])
    df_data = df_data.groupby(['date'])[
        ['mean_s', 'positive', 'negative']].mean().reset_index().sort_values('date')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df_data['date'],
        y=100 * (df_data['positive']) / (df_data['positive'] + df_data['negative']),
        base=0,
        name='Positive',
        marker_color=colors['pos1']
        ))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df_data['date'],
        y=100 * (df_data['negative']) / (df_data['positive'] + df_data['negative']),
        base=-100 * (df_data['negative']) / (df_data['positive'] + df_data['negative']),
        name='Negative',
        marker_color=colors['neg1']
        ))```
````

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirement is to zoom in / interact with the data, the clear answer is a [rangeslider](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = 365 * 15
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2008", periods=s),
                   "positive": np.random.uniform(0, 20, s),
                   "negative": np.random.uniform(0, -5, s),})

go.Figure([
    go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df["positive"], name="positive", marker_color="green"),
    go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df["negative"], name="negative", base=0, marker_color="red"),
    ]).update_layout(
    barmode="stack",
    xaxis={
        "range": [df.iloc[-200]["date"], df["date"].max()],
        "rangeslider": {"visible": True},
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "r": 0},
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob, but the rangeslider doesn't seem to change the bar width as I zoom in or zoom out. I want my bar width to stay within a certain range so that it doesn't look too thin or too thick as I zoom in/out. Any ideas?

Comment: they definitely do...  **rangeslider** has to interactions, 1) window location, where you drag it right and left 2) window size, where you drag handles on left and right - this definitely changes size of bars, get wider when you make window smaller, narrower when you make it wider

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I'll put it this way. I want the bar width to appear the same even when I zoom in or out. Perhaps making it automatically calculate the average of those bars to make the graph with even widths. If the bar width is too thin and there are a million bars, it gets painfully slow and the graph is not very visually appealing. When zoomed in, if the bar width gets too wide, it is also not visually appealing IMO. I was wondering if there's any function that does this job.

Comment: on line charts with a **rangeslider** I do use a call back in **dash** to change **range* on y-axis so that it matches window.  possibly same technique could be used to maintain bar width by setting x-axis range

Comment: Either way, a screenshot showing the same plot but with the rangeslider covering the whole period would be useful for people to assess whether this solves the issue or not. The screenshot provided doesn't display any additional feature for rangeslider compared to point-and-drag zoom on the OP's chart.

Comment: @Thrastylon I'm always ensure that my code works without needing g to construct data hence just paste into a jupyter env and you can find out easily.  another screenshot may not help many... it's try it and use it is far better approach